# Using the mutate function & making conditional statements, r

Tags: r, syntax

I have intervals of dates and time periods that I want to incorporate into a conditional statement. The problem lies somewhere in the "day" determination. I don't think it's going around the clock to include the am and pm times- what syntax could I use instead?

```
## 6.2 Narrative (Intervals) 
# Interval 1
  ## Interval Date Start  "2019-09-23"
  ## Interval Date End    "2019-10-05"
  ## Day Start Time       "21:01:00"
  ## Day End Time         "12:01:00"
  ## Night Start Time     "12:00:00"
  ## Night End Time       "21:00:00"
  ## Other Time
# Interval 2
  ## Interval Date Start  "2019-10-05"
  ## Interval Date End    "2019-10-30"
  ## Day Start Time       "21:01:00"
  ## Day End Time         "12:29:00"
  ## Night Start Time     "12:30:00"
  ## Night End Time       "21:00:00"
  ## Other Time

##6.3 Applying the tidyverse 
# Using the "case_when" function in the tidyverse in the place of a loop

    dml <- dml %>% mutate(period=case_when(
                         (ObservationDate >= "2019-09-23") 
                          & (ObservationDate <="2019-10-05") 
                          & (ObservationTime >= "12:00:00") 
                          & (ObservationTime <="21:00:00") ~"night",

                          (ObservationDate >= "2019-10-05")
                          & (ObservationDate <= "2019-10-30")
                          & (ObservationTime >= "12:30:00") 
                          & (ObservationTime <="21:00:00") ~"night",

                          (ObservationDate >= "2019-09-23") 
                          & (ObservationDate <="2019-10-05")
                          & (ObservationTime >= "21:01:00") 
                          & (ObservationTime <="11:59:00") ~"day",

                          (ObservationDate >= "2019-10-05")
                          & (ObservationDate <= "2019-10-30")
                          & (ObservationTime >= "21:01:00")
                          & (ObservationTime <= "12:29:00") ~"day",
                          TRUE ~"other"
                        )
                      )
```

Comment: Pleaase show a small  reproudcible example with `dput` as it is not clear about the classes of your dataset columns

Comment: I created them with 
# Create new split date and time columns
dml$ObservationDate <- as.Date(dml$dateTime)
dml$ObservationTime <- format(as.POSIXct(dml$dateTime) ,format = "%H:%M:%S")

Comment: krovinski, I believe akrun was asking you to provide something that we can use. Since we know nothing of `dml`, knowing even that you do `format` does nothing to help us from a starting point. And because comments are easily hidden or skipped, it's typically better to keep the question "complete" by [edit]ing your question and placing it there (within a code block). Thank you.

Comment: r2evans & akrun - thanks for following up - I realized I need an "or" syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
r2evans & akrun - thanks for following up - I realized I need an "or" syntax to complete the 24hours in a day- thanks           
     dml <- dml %>% mutate(period=case_when(
                          (ObservationDate >= "2019-09-23") 
                          & (ObservationDate <="2019-10-05") 
                          & (ObservationTime >= "12:00:00") 
                          & (ObservationTime <="21:00:00") ~"night",

                          (ObservationDate >= "2019-10-05")
                          & (ObservationDate <= "2019-10-30")
                          & (ObservationTime >= "12:30:00") 
                          & (ObservationTime <="21:00:00") ~"night",

                          (ObservationDate >= "2019-09-23") 
                          & (ObservationDate <="2019-10-05")
                          & ((ObservationTime >= "21:01:00") 
                          | (ObservationTime <="11:59:00")) ~"day",

                          (ObservationDate >= "2019-10-05")
                          & (ObservationDate <= "2019-10-30")
                          & ((ObservationTime >= "21:01:00")
                          | (ObservationTime <= "12:29:00")) ~"day",
                          TRUE ~"other"
                        )
```